# How to receive data from Telegram channel to webhook?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have set a Telegram webhook to `mybot` using node.js/express:

```
app.get('/hook', function (req, res) {    

        url='https://api.telegram.org/bot17xxxxx/setwebhook?url=https://example.com/hook'
            request(url, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
              }
            response.emit('close');
            });        
    });
```

and when I GET `https://example.com/hook` I could received into my bot console:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

Now I want to receive data from the bot so that when a users visits `https://telegram.me/mybot?start=xyz` and press `/start`, the bot should receive `xyz` in a post to `/hook` (at least that's my understaning of the procedure)

Here is the route that I have to receive the post:

```
app.post("/hook", function(req, res) {
            console.log(body);

});
```

But I see nothing happen in the bot when user visits `https://telegram.me/mybot?start=xyz` in her browser and presses `/start`.

What can be wrong here, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does example.com have a self-signed certificate for ssl connections (https)? If so, you need to configure the webhook properly: https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed

Answer (score 0):

Data comes in *req.body* on https://example.com/hook.  So you need to work with *(req.body)*

```
app.post("/hook", function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);

});
```

There will be something like that

```
{"update_id":1111111111,"message":{"message_id":2222,"from":{"id":333333333333,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Username","last_name":"Lastname","username":"username","language_code":"en},"chat":{"id":1111111111,"first_name":"Username","last_name":"Lastname","username":"username","type":"private"},"date":1518592199,"text":"xyz"}}
```

You can if you don't use something like bodyParser [bodyParser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) you should parse it

See simple example. All info in *body* and text in *text*

```
body=JSON.parse(req.body)
text=body.message.text
console.log(body)
console.log(text)
```